# Is there a 2 or 3-bit checksum algorithm

Tags: hash, checksum, integrity

Is there a 2 or 3 bit checksum algorithm that I can use to check my 6 bits of data for errors which I am reading in from an optical sensor that detects 8 bit patterns? I was not able to find anything.

Comment: @skypjack Thank you! This works great!

Comment: Added as an answer: if it solves, it's worth it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *xor* the first three bits with the second ones and append the result, then *xor* them again to check it on the other side.

Comment: Even though I said the sensor outputs 8 bits, I can reconfigure it to output 9 bits instead, so this will work great.

Comment: I worked out this simple algorithm: [link](http://pastebin.com/xCVVK9aL)
The benefit of it is, that it does not have duplicate numbers following each other and no 1234567 or reverse of it.

Comment: The output could actually be used in array form instead of the algorithm. There is probably not a big benefit of having the algorithm opposed to a small lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use two 3b/4b codes to validate the result:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding

Answer (score 0):

Not alot you can do with 0, 1, 2 or 3. Maybe get an integer value from your 6 bits and then do mod 4.